# how can i count customer_id where store_id count more than 1

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a db like down:

```
+---+-------------+----------
|id | customer_id | store_id|
+---+-------------+----------
|1  | 1           | 1001|
|2  | 1           | 1002|
|3  | 1           | 1001|
|4  | 1           | 1003|
|5  | 2           | 1001|
|6  | 2           | 1001|
|7  | 3           | 1001|
|8  | 3           | 1002|
|9  | 3           | 1001|
|10 | 4           | 1003|
|11 | 4           | 1001|
|12 | 4           | 1002|
+---+-------------+----------
```

i wish count distinct customer_id where shopping different shop_id more than value 1. (For exp. customer_id 1 shopping 1001, 1002 and customer_id 4 shopping 1001, 1002, 1003 and customer_id 3 shopping 1001,1002 but customer_id 2 just shopping 1001)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a nested query - the inner one filters only customer ids with more than one store id, and the outer one counts them:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   (SELECT   customer_id
        FROM     my_table
        GROUP BY customer_id
        HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT store_id) > 1) t
```

Note that the `group by` in the inner query already returns distinct customer ids, so the outer query doesn't need a `distinct` in its `count` call.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that has only one level of aggregation:

```
select count(distinct customer_id)
from t
where exists (select 1 
              from t t2
              where t2.customer_id = t.customer_id and
                    t2.store_id <> t.store_id
             );
```

This query should be able to take advantage of an index on `t(customer_id, store_id)`, which might give it a performance advantage.

Answer (score 0):

use sub query to count  store_id for every customer_id, and count rows with that count more than one

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (SELECT count(*) cnt
        FROM my_table
        GROUP BY customer_id
     ) t
WHERE cnt > 1
```